# State pressed color below src

Tags: android

I am using image button and a src on it with background.I have used png file with green background.I problem is that the on pressed state the color does not override the scr and stays at back.[image: State pressed screen]

State is pressed in screen.I want to override the black color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> <!-- pressed -->


<item android:state_pressed="false"

   android:drawable="@color/itsybitsy_green" /> <!-- default -->
```

```
 <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/main_eculator"
            android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_green" />
```

Comment: Are your `main_eculator` images transparent?

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira No my image is not transparent.I ahave used online 9-patch image tool and it removes tranperancy

Answer (score 0):

Pedro Oliveira has the right answer in his comment. 
Two solutions:
1) use png's with transparent backgrounds and use the background property of the image button to provide the right colour background 
2) use a state list for the src property and provide two images, one with green back and the other (say white on black back) for the pressed state.